# Axios post request not working for my app is deployed on Render

Tags: reactjs, axios, frontend, insert, render.com

In my simple MERN app, there's a submit but that triggers Axios.post, and saves an anime object to mongoDB, which gets rendered on the page.

This was working all fine in my machine, but after deploying frontend and the backend on render.com, Axios.post now did not add the object.

Here's App():

```
  const [animeList, setAnimeList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("https://recom-59hb.onrender.com/read").then((response) => {
      setAnimeList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const addAnime = async (anime) => {
    await Axios.post("http://localhost:10000/insert", anime);
    console.log(anime);
  };
```

Here's backend index.js:

```
app.post("/insert", async (req, res) => {
  const title = req.body.title;
  const opinion = req.body.opinion;
  const image = req.body.image;

  const anime = new AnimeModel({
    title: title,
    opinion: opinion,
    image: image,
  });

  try {
    await anime.save();
    res.send("inserted data");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

I tried changing the post link to "insert" and "website-name.onrender.com/insert" but still nothing works.

Any clue what link I should use for Axios.post?